# Rails fetch products based on minimum and maximum price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fetch

I have a rails app in which i have products and their variants.

**product.rb**

```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :variants

    scope :with_min_range, lambda { |min|
       where(" (variant_price) >= ?", "#{min.to_i}")
                         }
    scope :with_max_range, lambda { |max|

                           where("(variant_price) <= ?", ["#{max.to_i}"])
                         }

    def price_range
        return @price_range if @price_range
        return @price_range = ['N/A', 'N/A'] if active_variants.empty?
        @price_range = active_variants.minmax {|a,b| a.price <=> b.price }.map(&:price)
      end

   def price_range?
      !(price_range.first == price_range.last)
   end

    end
```

the way i fetch the price range of the product is

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <figcaption>
      <h4 class="aa-product-title"><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %></h4>
       <span class="aa-product-price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price_range.first, :locale => :in ) %>
         <% if product.price_range? %>
                                   to
          <%= number_to_currency(product.price_range.last, :locale => :in) %>
          <% end %></span>
     </figcaption>
<% end %>
```

Now you can see in the product.rb i want to fetch the product based on the  price so that in the `with_min_range` the result will be the products whose variants' minimum price range will be greater than the value of `min`
and in the `with_max_range` the result will be the products whose variants' maximum price would be less than the `max`

**P.S** - I have given `variant_price` in the where query just to give you idea what I want

Please help me to figure out its solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways i figured it out myself i needed to make join in the Product model so that `Product.joins(:variants)` after that in the scope I written

```
scope :with_min_range, lambda { |min|
       where(" variants.price >= ?", "#{min.to_i}")
                         }

scope :with_max_range, lambda { |max|

                           where("variants.price <= ?", "#{max.to_i}")
                         }
```

it now successfully fetch the record based on minimum and maximum price
If anyone can give a better answer then please !